# How to get Facebook friends who have used our app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated `Facebook` SDK in my application.

I want to get the list of the Facebook friends who have installed my app. The list should contain their details such as Facebook email id, Facebook name, etc.

I am using `graph api 2.5`.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..this code work for you got friend who install your app.

Refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends) for more information you got a id & name

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *Fbrequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                  parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id"}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [Fbrequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

       NSLog(@"%@",result);


    }];
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not get email of your friend. You can see in this link: [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

You just get email of user who allow your app get email. And no way for you get friend of this user's email.

And you can see at invite friend: [Invite Friend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite)

> My app needs the list of someone's friends that don't use the app. Can I have access to this info?
>
> The list of someone's friends who don't use your app is no longer available in v2.0. However, you can still enable people to tag friends using the Taggable Friends API.
>   Also, If your app is categorized as a game and you have a presence on Facebook Canvas, you can use the Invitable Friends API to render a custom invites dialog within your game. However, you'll still need to pass the tokens returned by the Invitable Friends API to the Requests Dialog to actually send the invites.
>
> My app needs to access detailed info from friends' profiles such as friends photos, likes, and so on. Can I have access to this info?
>
> We've removed access to friends' data in v2.0. However, we still support tagging friends through a new Taggable Friends API that you can use in your app.